# If I had 1 hour to explore Kuala Lumpur, what should I not miss?

Tags: planning, sightseeing, southeast-asia, malaysia, kuala-lumpur

Considering I get only 1 hour free time to experience the city of Kuala Lumpur, what is that one thing I should **not** miss?

*UPDATE*

I apologize if my question raised questions like '1 hour from where` and 'how are you arriving' and 'airport to city' - I assumed it was obvious that I would be starting off somewhere in the center of the city. It looks like Petronas towers is a great spectacle to check out! Thanks!

Comment: KL is a fairly big city, I think it would depend a lot on where abouts you were staring there! For example, as per [this answer](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/1781/26), if starting from the Airport an hour isn't enough to get to any bit of the city and back again!

Comment: Eat some laksa!

Comment: You don't say how you are coming and going, or where you start the one hour from. Assuming you are traveling by air (reasonable for KL), I would say the one thing you should not miss is your connecting flight. Quite expensive to get another ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the one hour is to spent in the city. I would go for the KL Tower instead of the Petronas Towers. The restaurant on the top of KL Tower takes approximately an hour to revolve and you will see more than just the Petronas Towers. Plus a nice Malaysian buffet.

The problem with this is that the taxi ride to / from KL Tower will increase the time over an hour.

So instead maybe head to KLCC, look at the Petronas Towers and then head to KLCC Park where there are views of other buildings. Then if you have time, go to the food court in KLCC and grab some Teh tarik (sweet tea) and Nasi Lemak.

Comment: It would be nice to know the downvote. It's a subjective answer to a subjective question with not much detail...

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer (or vote to close the question, keep it open or do anything else about it actually) but if you think the question is too subjective to answer, the proper course of action is… not answering it. Doing otherwise prevents poor questions from being deleted despite the fact they can't be answered satisfactorily.

Comment: Well, I don't think it's too subjective otherwise I wouldn't have answered it. :) It's a subjective question since railway buffs might want to go visit the Old Railway Station in KL. However I think there are people who may want ideas to see places in hurry.

Answer (score 8):

Usually questions like these get closed as subjective, but in KL's case I think there's a pretty objective answer: **The Petronas Towers**!

[image]
(courtesy me)

Especially at night...

[image]
(courtesy [Someformofhuman, Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Petronas_Panorama_II.jpg))

Sure, there are taller skyscrapers these days, but (IMHO) few are prettier, and nothing else in KL that you can cover in an hour comes close.  Easy to get to as well, hop on the KLIA Expres to Sentral and then take the LRT to KLCC.